# How do I reduce the cyclomatic complexity in this code?

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube, refactoring, code-complexity

I added the getCValue method to reduce the cyclomatic complexity, but the cyclomatic complexity still persists, how can I reduce it? Can I change this code using Regex, if I can how? Please help me.

Comment: You could try to reduce the nesting of those if-statements with some "early outs", e.g. `if (c != '\\') { outputCharArray[lengthOfOutput++] = c; continue; } c = inputCharArray[index++]; if (c == 'u') { ...; continue } ...`

Comment: your single method is doing too much work, create small methods

Comment: yes, but how do I break the method, it always has a dependency on the above variable

Comment: This question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could have a Map<Character, Character > to hold all the t, \t etc combinations.